# Why do banks use 4 pin passcodes with ATM cards?

Tags: security, encryption

Why do banks use 4 pin passcodes with ATM cards? I am wondering since I am thinking about pincode security.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're memorable:

> The concept of a PIN originates with
>   the inventor of the ATM, John
>   Shepherd-Barron. One day in 1967,
>   while thinking about more efficient
>   ways banks could disburse cash to
>   their customers, it occurred to him
>   that the vending machine model was a
>   proven fit. For authentication
>   Shepherd-Barron at first envisioned a
>   six-digit numeric code, given what he
>   could reliably remember. His wife
>   however preferred four digits, which
>   became the most commonly used length.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identification_number

From the article, assuming:

- 4 Digits
- No information known about PIN
- No information known about PIN generation method

There is apparently a 0.06% probability of guessing the correct PIN before the card is blocked. However, I'm not sure this takes into account that PINs can typically not start with zeroes, and even then the figure seems higher than I calculate (0.0003% if PINs starting with zeroes are allowed)

Comment: My bank requires 6 digits. #fml

Comment: @Alex R. - On the face of that it makes it pretty damn impossible to guess in 3 tries. The problem I see with 6 digits though is, many are forced to map them to something they know (e.g. part of an existing known number, or a word, or a handy mnemonic) and the result is actually decreased security rather than increased. Having said that, I manage to remember my credit card number, my bank number, my internet login number, many phone numbers etc. without too much trouble, and these are far longer. I do code though :-/

Answer (score 5):

In principle, the banks control all the places where you would use your 4-digit PIN, and they could therefore limit the number of incorrect attempts before your account is locked completely. This would make a brute-force attack impossible, meaning that 4 digits is plenty.

Answer (score 5):

A six-digit or eight-digit code would be more secure, but those darn humans seem to remember only four digits.

So, it's better than nothing, but four digits is pretty much what you can trust to the average customer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identification_number

Answer (score -1):

Probably for compatibility with legacy systems.

Also because that's what users have come to expect.